# php file only blank page without errors

Tags: php

i have got this php file, which shows me only a blank page.
i think i have an syntax error, but i doesn't get any errors.
I set these 2 lines to show me errors, but i get nothing.

> error_reporting(E_ALL);
>       ini_set('display_errors', 1);

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$var1= $_GET['var1'];   
$var2= $_GET['var2'];
$var3 = $_GET['var3'];

if ( (!empty($var1)) ||  (!empty($var2))  ||  (!empty($var3)) )

       echo "NOT EMPTY";

    } else {

        echo "EMPTY";

    }
?>
```

Comment: When it returns a blank page is almost certainly a code typo

Comment: print_r($var1);print_r($var2);print_r($var3);.Add the above line and tell what is the output

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. If you find out that you have asked the wrong question, then simply ask a new question. For more information, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298798/editing-questions-after-initial-post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a PARSE error. (like luweiqi told you)
If your script cannot be parsed, an error will be written away to the errorlog.
It will NOT appear in the output.
PHP considers that script as non-valid.

In cases like this, check your errorlog (in apache or wherever you store it)

Answer (score 2):

You missed out an opening curly bracket:

```
if ( (!empty($var1)) ||  (!empty($var2))  ||  (!empty($var3)) ) {
```

Your file already has a syntax error, thus to show the error, you'll need to set this in `php.ini`:

```
display_errors = on;
```

Answer (score 1):

open your `php.ini` and check this line `display_errors` if it `off` change to `on` :

```
display_errors = on;
```